# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '';' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in

Tags: php

I keep getting this error message when i go to my page online. I have gone through all the solutions on here in relation to this. But I just cannot seem to find an answer that will fix my code. 
My code is

```
function messages(){
    $message ='';

    //this is the line with the error
    if($_SESSION['success'] != '';) {

        $message = '<div class="msg-ok">' .S_SESSION['success'].'</div>';           $_SESSION['success'] = '';
        }
        if($_SESSION['error'] != '') {
            $message = '<div class="msg-error">'.$_SESSION['error'].'</div>';
            $_SESSION['error] = '';
        }
        echo "$message";
    }
```

Comment: did you fix this `S_SESSION`? that should be a dollar sign, not an `S`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove semi-column(;) from your condition :

```
if($_SESSION['success'] != '';)
```

Replace it

```
if($_SESSION['success'] != '')
```

And you can also use this like :

```
**if(!empty($_SESSION['success']))**
```

Comment: @David Lewis... If answer helps you then accept it.

Comment: I have tried both of the answers you have supplied but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @DavidLewis your problem is : replace it S_SESSION['success'] with $_SESSION['success']

Comment: I have fixed that but still receiving the same error I am afraid